# Flutter GoogleMap hasSize error logs when moving the map

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter

Every time I move the map on the screen it rethrows the error below. I have tried to move it in and out of various layers and wrapped it in sizedbox, expanded and other constraints and nothing seems to make a difference and I have no idea how to debug it.

```
Scaffold(
        body: SlidingUpPanel(
          onPanelSlide: (position) {
            // recenter marker
            bool openPanel = false;
            if (position > _panelHeightFraction) {
              openPanel = true;
            }
            _centerMarker(openPanel);
          },
          borderRadius: radius,
          isDraggable: true,
          controller: _panelController,
          maxHeight: 600 * _panelHeightFraction,
          defaultPanelState: PanelState.CLOSED,
          minHeight: 120,
          panel: _currentPanelContent,
          body: Stack(
            children: [
              GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _mapController.complete(controller);
                },
                onTap: (argument) {
                  if (_panelController.isPanelOpen) {
                    _panelController.close();
                  }
                },
                initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPos,
                markers: _markers,
                // polylines: Set.from(polyline),
                zoomControlsEnabled: true,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
              ),
              FilterRow(criteria: criteria)
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

```
[log] RenderBox was not laid out: RenderUiKitView#a4f3c NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
      'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
      Failed assertion: line 1972 pos 12: 'hasSize'
[log] #0      _AssertionError._doThrowNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:51:61)
      #1      _AssertionError._throwNew (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:40:5)
      #2      RenderBox.size (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1972:12)
      #3      RenderDarwinPlatformView._handleGlobalPointerEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/platform_view.dart:351:25)
      #4      PointerRouter._dispatch (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:98:12)
      #5      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:143:9)
      #6      _LinkedHashMapMixin.forEach (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:633:13)
      #7      PointerRouter._dispatchEventToRoutes (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:141:18)
      #8      PointerRouter.route (package:flutter/src/gestures/pointer_router.dart:133:5)
      #9      GestureBinding.handleEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:488:19)
      #10     GestureBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:468:22)
      #11     RendererBinding.dispatchEvent (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:439:11)
      #12     GestureBinding._handlePointerEventImmediately (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:413:7)
      #13     GestureBinding.handlePointerEvent (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:376:5)
      #14     GestureBinding._flushPointerEventQueue (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:323:7)
      #15     GestureBinding._handlePointerDataPacket (package:flutter/src/gestures/binding.dart:292:9)
      #16     _invoke1 (dart:ui/hooks.dart:328:13)
      #17     PlatformDispatcher._dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:410:7)
      #18     _dispatchPointerDataPacket (dart:ui/hooks.dart:262:31)
```

[image]